# Hebrew special charcters in regexp

Tags: php, regex, expression, hebrew

This is my code:

```
preg_replace('/[^{Hebrew}a-zA-Z0-9_ %\[\]\.\(\)%&-]/s', '', $q);
```

It's supposed to accept only a-z, A-Z, 0-9, any number of single white spaces and hebrew charcters.

I tried it in many varations and just couldn't get it to work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean that "you couldn't get it to work"? Did you try with some regexp testing tool like http://rubular.com/? Break this regexp down into small bits and test each one of them.

Comment: You forgot `\p`, so use `\p{Hebrew}`

Comment: Read more about the Unicode character properties here, to see the why and wherefore: http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php

Comment: @olleolleolle: Strictly speaking, this is not Unicode property. It is Unicode script.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. The PHP manual talks about their relationships like this: "**Sets of Unicode characters** are defined as belonging to certain **scripts**. A character from one of these sets can be matched using a script name. For example: `\p{Greek}`."

Answer (score 5):

In PCRE, `\p{xx}` and `\P{xx}` can take in either a [Unicode category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_character_property) name or [Unicode script](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Script_%28Unicode%29) name. The list can be found in [PHP documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php) or in [PCRE man page](http://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt).

For Hebrew script, you need to use `\p{Hebrew}`.

I also remove escape `\` for `.`, `(`, `)`, since they already loses their special meaning inside the character class `[]`. The `s` flag (`DOTALL`) is useless, since there is no dot metacharacter in your regex.

```
preg_replace('/[^\p{Hebrew}a-zA-Z0-9_ %\[\].()&-]/', '', $q);
```

---

### Appendix

From [Unicode FAQs](http://www.unicode.org/faq/blocks_ranges.html). It explains the difference between blocks and scripts. For your information, PCRE only has support for matching Unicode scripts and Unicode categories (character properties).

> ***Q: If Unicode blocks aren't code pages, what are they?***
>
> A: Blocks in the Unicode Standard are named ranges of code points. They are used to help organize the standard into groupings of related kinds of characters, for convenience in reference. And they are used by a charting program to define the ranges of characters printed out together for the code charts seen in the book or posted online.
>
> ***Q: Do Unicode blocks have defined character properties?***
>
> A: No. The character properties are associated with encoded characters themselves, rather than the blocks they are encoded in.
>
> ***Q: Does that even apply to the script for characters?***
>
> A: Yes. For example, the Thai block contains Thai characters that have the Thai script property, but it also contains the character for the baht currency sign, which is used in Thai text, of course, but which is defined to have the Common script property. To find the script property value for any character you need to rely on the [Unicode Character Database](http://www.unicode.org/ucd/) data file, [Scripts.txt](http://www.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/Scripts.txt), rather than the block value alone.
>
> ***Q: So block value is not the same as script value?***
>
> A: Correct. In some cases, such as Latin, the encoded characters are spread across as many as a dozen different Unicode blocks. That is unfortunate, but is simply the result of the history of the standard. In other instances, a single block may contain characters of more than one script. For example, the Greek and Coptic block contains mostly characters of the Greek script, but also a few historic characters of the Coptic script.

Comment: **+1** for this extended answer.

Answer (score 0):

you should change the file to utf 8 encoding for example: notepad++ go to encoding -> encode to UTF-8. and it shudold work:`preg_replace('/[^\p{Hebrew}a-zA-Z0-9_ %[].()&-]/u','', $q)` I also added "u" as a modifier.